# Issue with package installation of gganimate

Tags: r, github, r-package, gganimate

I want to install gganimate, but as I work behind a firewall in a corporate setting, install_github is not an option as it returns:

```
install_github("dgrtwo/gganimate")
Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
  Couldn't resolve host nam
```

I have tried to install it mannually, but the result I get is:

```
install.packages("C:/Users/stefanj/Downloads/gganimate.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/stefanj/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'gganimate/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
```

I found a work-around for a different library (rCharts):

```
library(downloader)
download("https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/archive/master.tar.gz", "rCharts.tar.gz")
install.packages("rCharts.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

But I can't find the tar.gz file for gganimate. I only have a zip file. Anyone knows how I can install source from a zip or where I can find the actuall tar.gz file for gganimate?

I have tried

```
install.packages("gganimate.zip", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

but it failed.

Comment: If you have Rtools installed, you could clone the github repos and use `devtools::build()` to compile the tar.gz file yourself.